# Weird network interrupt issue

Tags: linux, kernel, ethernet, drivers

in ifconfig output i am seeing `Interrupt 16` but when i check in `/proc/irq/` i am not seeing number `16` there.

following number i am seeing here. my driver is `broadcom tg3`

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ls /proc/irq/*/eno1*
/proc/irq/156/eno1-tx-0:

/proc/irq/157/eno1-rx-1:

/proc/irq/158/eno1-rx-2:

/proc/irq/159/eno1-rx-3:

/proc/irq/160/eno1-rx-4:
```

I am having very poor network performance so checking NAPI support and found that weird interrupt missing this :(

Comment: Why do you think these things are related?  Most interrupt lines now are virtual.